# Inconsistent results for Facebook redirect to HTTPS

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

My homepage redirects to the URL listed below to open an oauth dialogue with Facebook to validate user credentials.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=http://www.mywebsite.com/home/index.php" />
```

The Site URL (Website with Facebook login) in my Facebook App profile is

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
```

Everything works great for HTTP but when I recently implemented an SSL certificate I struggled to convert everything to HTTPS (changing HTTP to HTTPS in my redirect URLs and the Site URL in my Facebook app profile. I get the following Facebook error:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

I've fought with this a few hours at a time but was never successful and always just changed the redirect URL and the Site URL in my app profile back to HTTP. Last night it worked! I published the code and tested it successfully on two separate computers in both IE and Chrome. This morning I woke up to the same error code I was getting before.

Does anyone have any ideas why my Facebook oauth dialogue seems to be fickle when it comes to HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of a website with Facebook connect. At the top I have added a code to:

1. Detect if the user is authenticated yet and if not it will...
2. Detect if SSL is being used
3. If SSL is in use it will check to makes sure that whatever the
   current page is (gets dynamically) contains the URL you enter in the
   first variable ('$sslurl' in the top settings); otherwise, it will
   default back to $sslurl and add whatever page you were visiting to
   the end of it.
4. It will then use the correct url to authorize the user using the
   generated SSL url as the redirect_uri
5. The rest of the script is just a generic website with facebook
   connect setup

It's too long to place inside code tags so I put them in a text file here:

http://o-e.us/ssl-facebook-connect.txt

Hopefully it helps, Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a valid base domain specified in your app settings.